# How to check to which Tier our Number belongs to?

Tags: javascript

So we have that :

```
{TierLowerBound : 2,
 TierUpperBound : 5,
 TierName : 'Tier 1',
 TierDiscount : 0.15},

 {TierLowerBound : 6,
  TierUpperBound : 10,
  TierName : 'Tier 2',
  TierDiscount : 0.40}
```

And given number for example `let i=5;`
What can be the best way to find out to which of the tiers our number `i` belongs to?
I created simple `function isBetween`, some objects etc. but I am asking, because there are maybe some great ways in JS to deal with that kind of situation?

---

I'm using foreach loop to check every tier, so it's not as efficient as switch, but switch relays on fixed values, so it would be hard to evalute for instance this situation :

```
lowerBound = 5;
upperBound = 10;
number = 7;
```

Looking forward for an answer:)

**ANSWER**

```
getDiscount : function(number){
  let foundTier =  tier.tiersArray.filter(function(object){
  let isBetween = number >= object.TierLowerBound && 
                 ( number <= object.TierUpperBound || object.TierUpperBound  == 
                 'noLimit')  
  return isBetween;
}).values().next().value;

   return foundTier ? foundTier.TierDiscount : 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to be aggressive. "tiers" can mean a lot of things, and your question is either not clear enough, or has been asked a number of times already. Have you tried to use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) ?

Comment: No I didn't, since it has the same logic as basic loop with return -> iterating trough until finding specified element
 + basic array looping is faster.

I mean it's almost the same but just with prettier code. For example getting Key value of Map is instant.

I'm looking for for this kind of solution, like 'instant'

Comment: Are you sure a basic array loop is faster ? You are searching for a specific element in an array. So unless it is sorted (in which case you can do a dichotomic search), you cannot do better than O(n).

Comment: Yeah it is faster but not in complexity.
You know the compiler linking etc. It takes computer when we force him to link libraries, so when i write C-like array looping instead using JS Libraries with method .find(), i'm pretty sure - yeah, it's faster.

I guess Binary Search would be the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter:

```
const yourArrayOfObjects = [
{
        TierLowerBound: 2,
        TierUpperBound: 5,
        TierName: 'Tier 1',
        TierDiscount: 0.15
    },
    {
        TierLowerBound : 6,
        TierUpperBound: 10,
        TierName: 'Tier 2',
        TierDiscount: 0.40
    }
];

const returnObjectsWhereNumberFitsInBounds = n => {
   return yourArrayOfObjects.filter(element => element.TierLowerBound < n && element.TierUpperBound > n)
}

const magicNumberToTest = 4;

console.log(returnObjectsWhereNumberFitsInBounds(magicNumberToTest));
```

Comment: You are logging the function ^^ (also `a` is not defined)

Comment: You are right, @Seblor! I adopted the code and tested it, but I assumed we only target numbers between the lower and upper bounds. @Richard98PL you would obviously need to apply your own logic to **returnObjectsWhereNumberFitsInBounds**. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an array of objects with tier information, here is an approach:

```js
const tiers = [{
    TierLowerBound: 2,
    TierUpperBound: 5,
    TierName: 'Tier 1',
    TierDiscount: 0.15
  },
  {
    TierLowerBound: 6,
    TierUpperBound: 10,
    TierName: 'Tier 2',
    TierDiscount: 0.40
  }
]

function isBetween(numberGiven) {
  let categoryFound = {}
  tiers.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
    if (numberGiven >= arrayItem.TierLowerBound && numberGiven <= arrayItem.TierUpperBound) {
      console.log("The number requested, " + numberGiven + " is in " + arrayItem.TierName + " category!");
      categoryFound = arrayItem;
    }

  });
  return categoryFound;
}

isBetween(3);
isBetween(6);
isBetween(9);

// if you want to use the category in another place, call it like this:
const objInRange = isBetween(7);

console.log("objInRange: " + JSON.stringify(objInRange, null, 2));
```

Comment: forEach is bad solution since we can't return from it after finding one :)